# Early NoSuchMethodError whished by call of loader.loadClass()

Tags: java, linker, classloader

I want to test if the new version of my class CallingClass still works with my jar, even if the class has been compiled after it.

In my case, the CallingClass.m1() calls a method CalledClass.method() which doesn't exist in the jar. The execution of code leads to an NoSuchMethodError.

A need a solution to test the class CallingClass again the jar, but outside of the execution.

I have tried following

```
public class ResolvingClassLoader extends ClassLoader
{
    public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        return loadClass(name, true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        final ResolvingClassLoader loader = new ResolvingClassLoader();
        final String className = "CallingClass";
        loader.loadClass(className);
    }

}
```

and had hope the call of loadClass generate a NoSuchMethodError, as it resolves (i.e. links) the class. It is not the case. Do you know how to generate an "early" NoSuchMethodError?

Answer (score 0):

NoSuchMethodError is produced only when a method which does not exist is called, and thus you can produce one only by calling the method.